# Microsoft Office 2021 Interops not appearing in GAC folders

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, pia

I am upgrading from office 2019 to office 2021 and the interop dlls located in the gac folder are not there anymore, have these been moved to a new location?

Answer (score 1):

.Net Programmability Support must be selected when installing Microsoft Office if you want to get PIAs installed on the system. Or you need to install a redistributable package yourself. Otherwise, use Visual Studio to install or generate them. You can read more about different ways of installing PIAs on the system in the [Office primary interop assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2022) article.